# Pivot Table Showing Inaccurate Data in 1 Row

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I've been struggling to find the root cause of this problem. I have a raw data table in RAW DATA  worksheet (created a relationship with table in vlookup data (Image 2) to use power pivot), and I have a pivot table  OVERALL worksheet that I need to show the payload cycle for March 2021. All but 1 row showed correct data. Payload range 54.6~59.2 (image 3) should have 11 cycles (image 1). But instead, the cycles showed in the (blank) category of the pivot table. However, when I change the rated payload value from 91 to other values from far 91, like 100 and above (MAIN worksheet), the pivot table becomes accurate. I dont know why this happens.

[Excel macro file link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L8hZOL3vT9BXmsRDohRmZ35QGG6pbabi/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110192216995120670845&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Image 1

[image: Image 1]

Image 2

[image: Image 2]

Image 3

[image: Image 3]

Answer (score 0):

Your relationship for raw_data[UPPER LIMIT] and index_data[UPPER LIMIT] for 59.150 is failing.  I tried to pull in the RELATED() PAYLOAD, and got blanks for that limit.

In your V-look up data sheet I changed the UPPER LIMIT from "above" to 999.  That allowed both columns in your data model to be formatted as Decimal Number and fixed the missing cycles.